# Landing Pages and Pop Up Overlay

Tags: pages

On some of my landing pages, I now get Missing Required Argument(s) when i put in name and email on the pop up overlay.

Some I know used to work because I had sign ups from them.  Some of them still work and they are all clones of each other.  Established not GDPR related.

Is this an easy tweak?

Comment: As written, it's hard to see how this question has anything to do with WordPress development. Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/419060/edit) to clarify the connection (including code snippets to show what you've tried will help, too).